# Dynamic/automatic updated history in TFS/VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Is it possible to make the History window in Visual Studio to track the active selected item in the Source Control Explorer window?

Other source control software I have used have this option, and it makes it very easy to iterate through the files in a folder and see what has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do it out of the box, and I'm not aware of a plug-in that does that.  In VS 2012 the team moved the History view to be in the editor document well rather than a tool window making this mode of working even less likely I'm afraid.

That said, I'll pass the feedback along to the team who make the TFVC provider. Being an Eclipse guy myself I am familiar with that mode of working and certainly find it useful at times.